# how to use ag-grid (React version)'s API in chrome developer tools(F12)

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How to use ag-grid base on React API in chrome DevTools(F12).
test link: https://www.ag-grid.com/example/
such as

```js
$("ag-root-wrapper").***.gridOptions.api.**
```

API:https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-options/

my goal is in DevTools to use ag-grid's API to read/change the ag-grid table.
thanks.